# How to make items stay ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

Using horizontal scroll view when the user slide to the next page, the some of the current objects will fade away in the direction of motion as to user swipes and some of the objects will change place/size and then become part of the next page. It's similar to the "Magic Move" transition in keynote.

Also sometimes when a user swipes to the next page in the scroll view the objects each travel at a different speed in response to the swipe. So for example there 2 blocks in the centre of the screen (verticalally arranged) as the user is moving his finger block 1 travels all the way to the end while #2 is just behind it.
  How can I go about doing this?
Swift 3

Comment: Are you talking something "sticky"? As in, if a user scrolls 0.25 width and releases from scrolling, it shifts back to the current image/cell?

Comment: No, I reworded the question  to make it a bit clearer. @dfd